# Does sound come out of both audio ports?

Tags: windows-xp, audio, headphone-jack

My computer has two headphone jacks, and I haven't been able to listen to both of them at the same time. Do both of them output the same sound?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that both headphone jacks are from the **same audio card**, and the default sound balance settings **have not** been changed, then yes, the outputted audio should be **the same** from both jacks.

Answer (score 0):

Though the same connectors are used for a variety of applications, it is very uncommon to have more than one headphone jack on the same audio card. It is more likely the second output is actually a line out, designed to carry a signal to another audio device's 'line in', whereas the headphone jack is designed to drive headphones.

Though headphones hooked up to either port will produce sound, there are functional differences. The line out port may bypass volume controls, as well as having a different volume level altogether. The sound card may also adapt its behaviour, such as muting the speakers when headphones are connected, but not when something is plugged into the line out. Playing individual songs on both ports is generally not an option, however.